# Ubuntu disappeared from the grub menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I dual-booted ubuntu with windows 10 some months ago and it was working fine. After the holidays I realized that my ubuntu disappeared from the grub menu. I first checked if the storage partition was still there and it is. I am very new to this so I researched a bit and went on the bios settings to change the order of ubuntu and ubuntu wasn't there. I tried to then add a new boot as I saw on this website: https://itsfoss.com/no-grub-windows-linux/ (method 2). But I own a Lenovo and I did not find an option under the boot section.

I have no clue what to do, is it possible to get back to ubuntu? If so, how? Thanks.

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the BootInfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu disappeared from the grub menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429371/ubuntu-disappeared-from-the-grub-menu) - it appears you (accidentally?) posted your question twice